# jquery find table cell with value and highlight tr

Tags: jquery, css

What i have done:

```
$('#transport td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'TPS999';
}).addClass("marked");
```

now it highlights

how can i highlight that row where i found text (tr)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('#transport td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'TPS999';
}).closest('tr').addClass("marked");
```

Answer (score 1):

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anilk/SU4ha/)

Code

```
$('#transport td').filter(
function(t){
     if($(this).text() =="TPS999") {
        $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color','Red');
        // alert("i am in");
        return;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `closest('tr')` to get the parent `row` and return row instead of `td`.

```
$('#transport td').filter(function() {
    if($(this).text() == 'TPS999')
       return $(this).closest('tr');
}).addClass("marked");
```

OR, you can use [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to select all elements that contain the specified text and use `closest('tr')` to get the parent `td` and add class to it.

```
$('#transport td:contains("TPS999")').closest('tr').addClass("marked");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
var $cell = $('#transport td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'TPS999';
});

$cell.closest('tr').addClass("marked")
```